# Conditional Formatting with Custom Script Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a custom function using the script editor called "alwaysTrue()".

Using the function in the sheet works as expected:

[image]

When I try to use this for conditional formatting, it is simply ignored.

[image]

I've tested with a completely unknown method and this is just ignored too:

[image]

Is there a way to get this to work?

It seems crazy that you can define a custom method, which works as expected - yet you cannot use the custom method within conditional formatting.

p.s I am not really trying to use a custom formula to test if the value is "True", I have a far more complex version comparison method I wish to use. This will compare versions of software modules - so I can have a nice grid of modules and green/red if they are out of date or not. End result I am looking for is:

[image]

Example of the actual compare_version function:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G0RomvEhu4R0ZseE695Q1wkps5AOuwd4lYnTRqLsXeM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it a case of matching value in T? You can use relative referencing in conditional formula e.g. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e9213penSBO17kAZWayI5KEUdgfE5gg8ia7zJeHAs_I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No, sorry to be clear not a case of just matching the value. It's a case of using a custom script within the comparison. Check W4 in the example above, it is green because 0.1.4-patch1 is bigger than 0.1.4.

Comment: How about using custom formula result in hidden column https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j_Wgrh22pl-5MRFGWqMsS9YEZpQQ_k0lgdfzb7_uNkQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That would work, but I'd really like to just use the custom formulae in the conditional formatting - there are a lot of 'hacks' to work around the issue - but a real solution would be nice,

Comment: I can't find any documentation to say for sure but I'm assuming custom functions don't work in conditional formatting. Another option would be to attach to onEdit() and onOpen() events e.g. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-content

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Sheets, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the proper JSDOC to the custom function.
Read more at: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

```
/**
 * Returns TRUE
 *
 * @return TRUE
 * @customfunction
 */
function ALWAYSTRUE(){
 return "TRUE";
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I did this but it made no difference. If you'd like to create the custom function and add it to a sheet proving it works I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If `Client A` is in U1 then this result:

[image]

may be achieved by selecting U2 to W4, standard filling with reddish, and Format, Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=find($T2,U2)
```

with Default fill, <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: The version comparison is more complicated, because 0.1.4-patch1 shows that a local change has been made against the latest version, thus is green not red. This is W4 for reference. P.S I would like the ability to use a custom script, and whilst this is probably an acceptable work around for most that wasn't what I was trying to achieve.